# custom category tree in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i want to create a tree of categories in wordpress like this :

```
<ul>
    <a href=""> PARENT1 </a>
    <li><a href=""> CHILD 1-1</a></li>
    <li><a href=""> CHILD 1-2</a></li>
     .
     .
     .
</ul>
<ul>
    <a href=""> PARENT2 </a>
    <li><a href=""> CHILD 2-1</a></li>
    <li><a href=""> CHILD 2-2</a></li>
     .
     .
     .
</ul>
```

i want something that creates categories list in above format and show only categories which have children and hide those who don't

I Tried Something like this but it didn't give me what i wanted

```
<?php $args = array(
'type'                     => 'post',
'child_of'                 => 0,
'parent'                   => '',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 0,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'exclude'                  => '',
'include'                  => '',
'number'                   => '',
'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
'pad_counts'               => false 
);
$cats = get_categories( $args );
foreach( $cats as $cat) {
    if($cat->parent == 0) {
        $head = $cat->name;
        $cat_id = $cat->term_id;
    }
    echo "<a href=''>" . $head . "</a>";
    wp_list_cats("sort_column=NAME&optioncount=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$cat_id}");
}
```

?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks For Your Response , I Found the Solution : 
This Code Works Fine

```
     $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'child_of'                 => 0,
            'parent'                   => 0,
            'orderby'                  => 'name',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 1,
            'hierarchical'             => 0,
            'exclude'                  => '',
            'include'                  => '',
            'number'                   => '',
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false 
            );
            $cats = get_categories( $args );
            foreach( $cats as $cat) {
                if($cat->parent == 0) {
                    $parent_cat = null;
                    $head = $cat->name;
                    $head_id = $cat->term_id;
                }
                echo "<ul><a class='parent-category' href=''>" . $head . "</a>";                                                    
                wp_list_cats("sort_column=NAME&optioncount=0&hierarchical=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$head_id}&show_option_none=");
                echo "</ul>";
            }
```

Comment: `wp_list_cats` is [deprecated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_cats), use `wp_list_categories`

Answer (score 6):

(works for any taxonomies,including "category")

```
$your_taxonomy='category';

function my_Categ_tree($TermName='', $termID, $separator='', $parent_shown=true ){
    $args = 'hierarchical=1&taxonomy='.$TermName.'&hide_empty=0&orderby=id&parent=';
            if ($parent_shown) {$term=get_term($termID , $TermName); $output=$separator.$term->name.'('.$term->term_id.')<br/>'; $parent_shown=false;}
    $separator .= '-';  
    $terms = get_terms($TermName, $args . $termID);
    if(count($terms)>0){
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            //$selected = ($cat->term_id=="22") ? " selected": "";
            //$output .=  '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'" '.$selected .'>'.$separator.$category->cat_name.'</option>';
            $output .=  $separator.$term->name.'('.$term->term_id.')<br/>';
            $output .=  my_Categ_tree($TermName, $term->term_id, $separator, $parent_shown);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**Then you can output:**
1) target category(taxonomy) tree, using specific ID

```
echo my_Categ_tree($your_taxonomy, 0 );
```

2) All categories/taxonomies

```
foreach (get_terms($your_taxonomy, array('hide_empty'=>0, 'parent'=>0)) as $each) {
    echo my_Categ_tree($each->taxonomy,$each->term_id);
}
```

Comment: I have a question as below. It's been a long time since your answer, but maybe you have a method you want to share. Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055042/list-the-category-tree-of-all-the-product-cat-categories-in-wordpress

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product-type',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'title_li'     => '',
  'hide_empty'   => false
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>



You can use the wp_list_categories function also for taxonomies.
```

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
>
> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39125/custom-taxonomy-tree-view

Answer (score 2):

It's a very old post, but maybe some more clean code. For all the options of [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) please see [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/). Feel free to make it more generic:

```php
function build_custom_category_tree ($activeCatId, $activeParentId, $parentId = 0) {

    $output = '';
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custom_categories',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'parent' => $parentId
    ) );

    if (count($terms)) {

        $output .= '<ul>';

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $output .= '<li class="custom-cat' . ($term->term_id === $activeParentId || $term->term_id === $activeCatId ? ' active' : '') . '">';
            $output .=  $term->name;
            $output .=  build_custom_category_tree($activeCatId, $activeParentId, $term->term_id);
            $output .= '</li>';
        }

        $output .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And then in your template:

```html
<div>
   <?= build_custom_category_tree($catIdOfPost, $rootIdOfCat) ?>
</div>
```